# RazorEngine and Visual Studio 2015 IntelliSense

Tags: razorengine

This post is not about ASP.NET MVC.

I am using RazorEngine for template processing available here:

https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/

The documentation states that I can have IntelliSense if I follow the instructions below:

https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html

However, VS shows the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'RazorEngine' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Also the following errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System'
>   The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web'
>   The type or namespace name 'WebPages' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Web'

Am I getting the errors because I am editing the .cshtml in a command line project where the instruction assumes I use the web project? That doesn't make sense since RazorEngine does not have any project type requirement.

How can I address the issue? How can I edit .cshtml files in a command line project with IntelliSense without all of the above errors?

---

**Found the answer**

RTFM

According to the web page:

Your project output path is set to bin\ instead of bin\Debug\ and bin\Release.
**another possible solution is to copy RazorEngine.dll and System.Web.Razor.dll to bin.**

I am not deleting the post since it might help others.

Comment: my output is set to bin\ and dll's are set to Copy Local but still I can't get Linq

Comment: @dotjoe, this question relates to RazorEngine https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine. Note the question tag. I guess you are using other types of project.

Comment: I'm using Antaris/RazorEngine in a vs 2015 class library project...get those errors no matter what I try. This issue sums it up https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/368

Comment: Are you  saying that the solution was to leave the bin\Debug output path and copy the dll's to bin? Because I've tried all combo's and can't get intellisense to stop complaining..the templates run fine with RazorEngine it's just the intellisense that is messed up.

Comment: @dotjoe, I remember, do you copy to the startup project's BIN or the class library folder BIN?

Comment: class library bin

Comment: @dotjoe, I don't have my project open, it is in another VM. Can you try both?

Comment: @AllanXu, you should post your solution as a separate answer, rather than editing it into the question.  [This is actively encouraged!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: most IntelliSense is working after changing the output to `bin` but I still can't get IntelliSense for `System.Linq`.  If I hover over the line `@using System.Linq` it says `The using directive for 'System.Linq' appeared previously in this namespace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer

RTFM

According to the web page:

Your project output path is set to bin\ instead of bin\Debug\ and bin\Release. another possible solution is to copy RazorEngine.dll and System.Web.Razor.dll to bin.